# How do I access an element in a constant array

Tags: php, php-5.6

Since the PHP 5.6 it's possible do define a constant array like this:

```
const MY_CONSTANT = array('fruit'=>'apple');
```

However I am not clear on how exactly I can access array elements that use either keys or indexes. PhpStorm complains about a syntax error when I try to do it like this:

```
self::MY_CONSTANT['fruit'];
```

Comment: Whats about MY_CONSTANT['fruit']?

Comment: What is the PHP base version at your PHP Storm ? 
I think that your syntax is ok..

Comment: but only if your constant is in a class

Comment: @A.Blub Nope, you can define array constants outside of a class context - [proof](http://3v4l.org/QOVrP)

Comment: shure. But you cant get it thourgh self:: them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you're using is fine and should work for 5.6+

PhpStorm shows an error because of an outstanding [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26366); the full support of constant arrays was completed after the first release candidate, so this is not entirely surprising ;-)

Since 8.0.3 you can already define constant arrays, but you need to indirectly reference them, i.e.:

```
$tmp = self::MY_CONSTANT;
echo $tmp['fruit'];
```